# WSO2 BPS rest API tests

Tags: wso2, wso2-business-process

I didn't find such kind of an information in your documentation so I would like to know if there any opportunities/tools for testing API for the whole diagram? like a set of API call one after another? Will it be OK if I put several rest API calls in one test method? Are there better approaches for doing that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We didn't find any lib for that but we used RestAssured library for testing API calls.